# unable to create object in java with lombok noargsconstructor added with Pojo Cla

Tags: lombok

**unable to create object in java with lombok **noargsconstructor **added with Pojo Class**

1. I have created a** POJO class Employee**. Code mentioned below-

   @Data
   @NoArgsConstructor
   @AllArgsConstructor(access = AccessLevel.PUBLIC)
   @Builder
   public class Employee {

   ```
    @NonNull int employeeId;
    @NonNull private String firstName;
    @NonNull private String middleName;
    @NonNull private String lastName;
   ```

   }
2. In Another class, i want to create object of Employee class using the below code

   Employee e1= new Employee(1,"firstTest","middleTest","lastTest");**

   // Unable to instantiate this class  with the values.                                              Seems that @NoArgsConstructor is not    working. //Compile time error occured

Any help / suggestion would be much appreciate. Thank You.